# QueryInterface on IMFMediaBuffer to IMFDXGIBuffer returns E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

I have a function that takes in an `IMFSample` pointer as a parameter. I am able to successfully convert it to an `IMFMediaBuffer` object. However, when I call `QueryInterface` for the `IMFDXGIBuffer` on the `IMFMediaBuffer` object, the `HRESULT` returned is `E_NOINTERFACE`.

Here is a very basic version of the method in which this is happening (for reference, the real function is based off of the `CPresenter::ProcessFrame` method in Microsoft's DX11VideoRenderer project).

```
HRESULT TPresenter::ProcessFrame(IMFMediaType* pCurrentType, IMFSample* pSample, UINT32* punInterlaceMode, BOOL* pbDeviceChanged, IMFSample** ppOutputSample)
{
    TObject::ThreadLock();

    // Code to Check Shutdown and pointers

    *pbDeviceChanged = FALSE;
    DWORD cBuffers = 0;
    HRESULT res = pSample->GetBufferCount(&cBuffers);

    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        TObject::ThreadRelease();
        return res;
    }
    IMFMediaBuffer* pBuffer = nullptr;
    IMFMediaBuffer* pEVBuffer = nullptr;
    if (1 == cBuffers)
    {
        res = pSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pBuffer);
    }
    else
        res = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);

    // Code to Check Interlace mode

    // Code to get the Device and Device Context for Direct3D

    IMFDXGIBuffer* mfdxgiBuff = nullptr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* d3dText = nullptr;
    UINT resourceIndex = 0;
    res = pBuffer.QueryInterface<IMFDXGIBuffer>(&mfdxgiBuff);      // Currently returns E_NOINTERFACE
    if (SUCCEEDED(res))
        res = mfdxgiBuff->QueryInterface<ID3D11Texture2D>(&d3dText);
    if (SUCCEEDED(res))
        res = mfdxgiBuff->GetSubresourceIndex(&resourceIndex);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        ThreadRelease();
        return res;
    }

    // Continues on
}
```

OS: Windows 10 Home (Version 20H2)

VS: Community 2019 (Version 16.10.0)

Every resource I've seen relative to getting an `IMFDXGIBuffer` from an `IMFMediaBuffer` is saying to use the `QueryInterface` method. Is it possible that Media Foundation has updated requirements regarding this procedure (new way we have to do this)? Or is there something I should be telling Media Foundation so that way, when these  samples are provided, the `IMFDXGIBuffer` is available?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing behavior by design.

Some buffers are backed by system memory, others - by D3D11 2D textures. You are assuming that the input is a texture while effectively it is a plain memory buffer.

You need a separate code path to handle this case (or you could possibly have an additional transform, including possibly third party one, that uploads data to video memory and ensures the samples are backed by textures).

Comment: I’ve been doing a lot of research on this and it seems right now that adding a Transform node is the better option. However, is there is a built-in transform I should use or should I look into implementing my own? I really think there should be a built in one but finding one that supports Direct3D 11 is proving elusive.

Comment: No built-in MFT of this kind.

Comment: But it should be possible to write a transform whose only job it is to take in samples and make sure that the output samples have a surface backing them? Are there any pitfalls you foresee (that I should be aware of)?

Comment: This is possible and this should work out.